Rejection region for the likelihood ratio test (uniform distribution)
Let $x_1 ... x_n$ be sampled from a uniform distribution with $f(x;\theta) = (1/\theta), \theta; >0, x \in [0,\theta].$
After finding the likelihood function for the hypotheses:
$H_0 : \theta = \theta_0 ~\textrm{vs} ~H_A : \theta \neq \theta_0$
So far I have found that the ratio test is
$\Lambda(\theta)= (\bar{X}/\theta_0)^n$ where $\bar{X}$ is the maximum value of x sampled.
If I am not attempting to define a rejection region I am slightly lost, do I define c in relation to this ratio test or define it as a function of the estimated value of X? Still having issues wrapping my head around stats, thanks in advanced.

Please fix your formatting.  Note that with Mathjax, $\theta$ is "\theta" not "&theta" and you seem to have a lot of semicolons that serve no purpose.


Double check your alternative. Are you definitely looking to define a two-sided test? 2. Defining a rejection rule in terms of $X_{(n)}=\max{X_1,X_2,...,X_n}$ or in terms of some monotonic transformation of $X_{(n)}$ (with a corresponding transformation of the rejection region) leads to equivalent tests. If you had a rule like "Reject if $X_{(n)}\in R_0$" or "Reject if $(X_{(n)}/\theta_0)^{n}\in R_1$", for some sets (regions) $R_0$ and $R_1$, then (if you do it right), the contents of the two sets will correspond to rejecting the same collections of possible samples.


Of course, if this is homework (as it appears) you might have been expected to do one or the other specifically. We can't tell that from your post. You will have information we do not.
